# How to find the equation? (Integral problem)

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

Here is a problem in our homework, I've never seen an integral written like that.. what does this question mean and how to solve it? Help please!! :(

> Given that $\displaystyle 3x^2-12=\int_a^xf(t)~dt$, find a formula for $f(x)$ and a value of $a$.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hint: take the derivative of both sides of the equation with respect to $x$.

Comment: but why the question gives the right side as f(t)dt and not f(x)dx?

Comment: Because you can’t use the same symbol for the dummy variable of integration and for a limit of that integration; that would make no sense. Remember, for each value of $x$ the integral $\int_a^xf(t)dt$ is simply a **number**, and it would be the same number if you wrote $\int_a^xf(u)du$ instead.

Comment: i got f(x)=6x, but what to do next? Like what does it help to find a?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT: This is a problem about the fundamental theorem of calculus. It says that if

$$F(x)=\int_a^xf(t)~dt\;,$$

then $F'(x)=f(x)$. You’ve been given $F(x)$; use the fundamental theorem to find the $f(x)$. To find $a$, notice that $\int_a^xf(t)~dt=0$ when $x=a$. For what $x$ is your $F(x)$ equal to $0$?

Answer (score 3):

As @tetori noted, Take the derivative of both sides. This is allowed becuase the conditions of Fundmental Theorem satisfied for it. So $$(3x^2-12)'=\left(\int_a^x f(t)dt\right)'=f(x)$$ So $$6x=f(x)$$ Now we have $$3x^2-12=\int_a^x 6tdt=3t^2\big|_a^x=3x^2-3a^2$$ So $3a^2=12$.

Comment: Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, and Babak, to the rescue! +1 :-)